# passing 'const' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers when using class template to create dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, dynamic

so I've created a class template which Im using in another class Registration, to create an array of type Result (which is another class) and I'm trying to read some information into it. I'm now getting the error `REGIST.CPP|75|error: passing 'const Vector<Result>' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]|`.

Another thing I'm confused about, why does the error say my Vector is a const?

I am not too sure what the problem is? Below is some sample code for where the error occurs, as well as my Vector.h class template.

Registration.h:

```
void Registration::writeFile(ostream & os) const{

    os << "Student ID: " << GetStudentID() << '\n'
     << "Semester:   " << GetSemester() << '\n';

  for(unsigned i = 0; i < count; i++)
    os << results[i] << '\n'; //error occurs at this line.

    //note: Results was declared as private variable in the header file as Vector<Result> results;


}
```

Vector.h:

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Vector
{
    public:
        Vector(int size = 10);
        ~Vector();

        void initialize(int from);
        void expand();
        void push(const T &element);
        int size(){return this->nrofel;}

        T& operator[](int index);


    private:
        T **data;
        int capacity;
        int nrofel;

};

template <class T>
Vector<T>::Vector(int size){

    this->capacity = size;
    this->nrofel = 0;
    this->data = new T*[this->capacity];

    initialize(this->nrofel);

}

template <class T>
T& Vector<T>::operator[](int index){

    if(index < 0 || index >= this->nrofel){

        throw("Out of bounds.");

    }

    return *this->data[index];

}

template <class T>
void Vector<T>::initialize(int from){

    for(size_t i = from; i < capacity; i++){

        this->data[i] = nullptr;

    }

}

template <class T>
Vector<T>::~Vector(){

    for(size_t i = 0; i < capacity; i++){

        delete this->data[i];

    }
    delete[]this->data;
}


template <class T>
void Vector<T>::expand(){

    this->capacity *= 2;

    T ** tempData = new T*[this->capacity];

    for(size_t i = 0; i < this->nrofel; i++){

        tempData[i] = this->data[i];

    }

    this->data = tempData;

    initialize(this->nrofel);

}

template <class T>
void Vector<T>::push(const T& element){

    if(this->nrofel >= this->capacity){

        this->expand();

    }

    this->data[this->nrofel++] = new T(element);

}


#endif // VECTOR_H
```

My vector class compiles fine so I'm hoping there's no issues there, this is the only error I seem to get when I try and compile.

Comment: What is on REGIST.CPP|75| where compiler shows you an error?

Comment: @ForEveR it shows me the error at os << results[i] << '\n'; in my Registration class, under the method writeFile.

Comment: Then looks at answers, problem is in operator [].

Answer (score 1):

Your member function is marked `const`, so all data members are considered `const` within it.

Otherwise a `const` member function would be able to modify the object it's part of.

You should add a `const` version of `operator[]` that can be used in cases like this.

`size()` should also be marked `const`.

Comment: Thank you for that. It compiles and runs fine now, but I get an error in the console as described in my comment for the answer above

Comment: @thedafferg That's a separate issue which you can now go and debug. The message suggests you threw `const char*` and never caught it, and since all standard library exceptions inherit from `std::exception`, it must be your `throw("Out of bounds.");`. So find out why that's triggering.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `operator[]` for `Vector` [const-correct](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness)

```
T& operator[](int index);
const T& operator[](int index) const; //version for const Vector instances
```

The implementation of both overloads may (and probably should) be the same. You should also check other functions for const-correctness (for now, `size()` should definitely be `const`).

Or just use `std::vector`, it has all of these things done.

Comment: This is part of an exercise for my lab work, and I am not allowed to use the std::vector. Thanks for your advice, I've now added the const overload of the operator and the program compiles and runs, but I get the message 'terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*' and the program terminates. Any idea what this means?

Comment: @thedafferg Exception was thrown and not caught. AFAIK, no standard library would ever throw `const char*`, so it must be thrown by your code (or some other library)